# Android ORMLite abstract method not implemented error

Tags: android, ormlite

I have a pre populated database in my application.  I get this error when I run my project:

```
06-17 17:15:22.554: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(482): java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method not implemented
06-17 17:15:22.554: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(482):     at com.j256.ormlite.android.AndroidDatabaseConnection.compileStatement(AndroidDatabaseConnection.java)
06-17 17:15:22.554: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(482):     at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.mapped.MappedPreparedStmt.compile(MappedPreparedStmt.java:39)
06-17 17:15:22.554: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(482):     at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.StatementExecutor.buildIterator(StatementExecutor.java:190)
06-17 17:15:22.554: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(482):     at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.StatementExecutor.query(StatementExecutor.java:134)
06-17 17:15:22.554: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(482):     at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.StatementExecutor.queryForAll(StatementExecutor.java:111)
06-17 17:15:22.554: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(482):     at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.queryForAll(BaseDaoImpl.java:215)
06-17 17:15:22.554: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(482):     at com.tabir.ruya.Ruya.setText(Ruya.java:46)
06-17 17:15:22.554: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(482):     at com.tabir.ruya.Ruya.onCreate(Ruya.java:29)
06-17 17:15:22.554: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(482):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
06-17 17:15:22.554: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(482):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
06-17 17:15:22.554: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(482):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
06-17 17:15:22.554: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(482):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
06-17 17:15:22.554: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(482):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
06-17 17:15:22.554: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(482):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-17 17:15:22.554: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(482):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-17 17:15:22.554: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(482):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
06-17 17:15:22.554: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(482):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-17 17:15:22.554: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(482):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
06-17 17:15:22.554: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(482):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
06-17 17:15:22.554: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(482):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
06-17 17:15:22.554: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(482):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here my code when I query records with Dao interface ,

```
List<SimpleRuya> accountList = simpleRuyaDao.queryForAll();
String ruya=accountList.get(2).getRuya();
```

At the `Databasehelper` side I have this code

```
public Dao<SimpleRuya, Integer> getSımpleRuyam() throws SQLException {
    if(simpleRuyaDao==null){
        simpleRuyaDao=getDao(SimpleRuya.class);
    }
    return simpleRuyaDao;
}
```

What causes this problem ? thanks.

Comment: I'm getting the same error did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the problem is here but it looks possibly like you have a mismatch between your `ormlite-android` and `ormlite-core` packages.

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method not implemented
    at AndroidDatabaseConnection.compileStatement(AndroidDatabaseConnection.java)
```

I've never seen this message before.  Also, you can verify that both the core and android jars are both in the build path.

Best of luck.

Comment: This is what has happened with me two or three times--I had a referenced project that used one version of OrmLite, and another referenced project that inadvertently used a different version.

Comment: yes the problem is mismatch between packages, some ormlite-core function doesnt work on Android , you have to use ormlite-android.

Answer (score 0):

hey which version of ormlite you are using ? I've got the same error while using ormlite 4.25
but its perfectly working with ormllite4.20

Try with ormlite 2.20